# hashing file in custom pattern

Tags: php, file, hash, md5

Fairly simple. How can I make a single function to create a multi-valued hashed url.

So for example *getfile.mysite.ltd/file/dl.php?file_id=10101* is alright but I do not want to disclose file_id. For such reason I am fetching files via universal file hash that is stored in SQL. Which is a MD5 of the files name.

Here is how the thing looks in my SQL record

```
 my-vacation-image.jpg -> b16f48c6cfd73bb9bfb058c95175537f
```

but I wan't to make it bit more complex as examle below

```
 my-vacation-image.jpg -> ce591714-d1e8-46d5-bbfa-23b45bea81e2
```

Any ideas or suggestions as to how?

Comment: You could use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to split the hash into pieces and then just add the dashes.

Comment: @Supericy actually I did not think about that, more like i forgot about subst function in php. Thanks ;)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what purpose does adding the dashes have?

Comment: yeah unless each segment is suppose to mean something different adding slashes to make it 'appear' more obscure really provides no benefit at all.

Comment: @Supericy and Cryptic actually each segment has a meaning. user_hash - sub_domain_location_hash - path_to_file - path_to_file - actual_file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dashedHash = implode('-', str_split($hash, 5));
```